# Javascript get ID of a child element using information about the parent

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I have a div created using javascript.

The div has a varying number of child elements that are all check boxes.

I want to retrieve the id's of all the checkboxes using a loop.

The div has been passed through into the class I am using, and has been called:

```
oInput
```

I know this is working fine as I am able to retrieve the number of child elements that the div has, using the following line:

```
oInput.childNodes.length
```

But my problem is I do not know how to retrieve the id of the child elements. All I want to do is to get the id's to display in an alert box for now.

So far I have:

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < oInput.childNodes.length; ii++)
        {
            var childId = oInput.childNodes[ii].id;
            alert("Child " + childId);
        }
```

But this is not the correct solution. I have searched around but there does not seem to be a clear answer to this question anywhere. I am only looking for a solution using javascript that will display the answer in the alert box in the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="oInput">
    <input id="1" type="text">
    <input id="2" type="text">
    <input id="3" type="text">
    <input id="4" type="text">
    <input id="5" type="text">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oInput = document.getElementById('oInput'),
            oChild;
    for(i = 0; i < oInput.childNodes.length; i++){
        oChild = oInput.childNodes[i];
        if(oChild.nodeName == 'INPUT'){
            alert(oChild.id);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I put the 'script' tag in the header it didn't work because the page hadn't fully loaded and the div did not exist yet - perhaps that was your problem?

Tested in Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome.

Comment: Thst is correct, in my case there was an extra parent causing my result to be undefined

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
var oInput = document.getElementById('oInput');
for (var ii = 0; ii < oInput.childNodes.length; ii++)
{
    var childId = oInput.childNodes[ii].id;
   if(typeof(childId) !== 'undefined')
    alert("Child " + childId);
}
```

Comment: @Alex simply use if(typeof(childId) !== 'undefined') in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this but the one I've found most reliable is using jQuery:

```
$("#myElementID").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function (){
  alert("Child " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Alternatively, you can use your code, but just modifying it a bit:

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < oInput.childNodes.length; ii++)
{
    var currentChild = oInput.childNodes[ii];

    // this check is to make sure that the child you've selected is an input
    if (currentChild.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input"){

       // now you want to make sure you only retrieve the id's of checkboxes 
       if (currentChild.type.toLowerCase() == "checkbox"){

           var childId = oInput.childNodes[ii].id;
           alert("Child " + childId);
       }
    }
}
```